Whole house carbon filter for home with well water
We've got a private well in our house and a whole-house water softener and an R/O filter that provides water to every tap in the house.  We have an R/O filter for a specific kitchen drinking-water tap, but I am curious what it would involve to install a whole-house carbon filter.  Can they keep up with the water needs of a large household?  Does it cause problems for periodic high-use things (like showers, dish-washers, etc.)?  Would you install it in between the well and the pressure tank or between the pressure tank and the rest of the house?

Do you need it(not want only)?  Have you had your water tested to see if a carbon filter will work?

"Need" is a complicated word.  We got out water tested and there are some things in our well water that aren't great (and that are filtered by carbon filters).  We have an R/O filter which solves most of the problem, but I'm trying to figure out how complicated/feasible it would be to carbon filter everything to have a more complete solution.

You seem to have need covered, it will filter out nasties in you water.  Will need to find out if you need the R/O filter plus the carbon filter, or if one will remove everything(better flow).  Each extra filter/softener in the system will reduce the flow flow a bit.  Hard to tell if it would reduce flow enough to bug you.

I have the RO filter for our drinking water.  But it doesn't produce enough water (or in all the faucets) to cover all the water that enters our mouths.  For instance, teeth-brushing, vegetable washing, etc.   So I'm just trying to figure out whether a whole-house carbon filter is feasible to install without causing problems.

Aqua-Pure AP904
